# Hiding Menu From Specific Pages

Tags: menus, pages

I’m trying to hide the menu page completely from this page:

http://ultimate-templates.com/splash-page

I’m using Divi 3.0, and have tried – through online tutorials – to hide it using the following in my styles css sheet:

```
.page-id-27820 top-menu-nav {
display: none important;
}
```

That didn’t do anything, aside from making the menu look a little weird (and dropping the search magnifying glass down a bit), and I removed the code – the search button still looks weird.

if anyone could help me with how to remove the menu completely (and logo etc) from that one page, I’d be very much appreciative!

Answer (score 4):

Created a simple image for you on how to get page id and menu attributes.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/zibhieyo3s6a5bs/Mailbird_2017-01-27_00-57-39.png

You need to get the page_id, exactly as you did:

```
.page-id-27820
```

and hide the menu, like so:

```
.page-id-27820 #top-menu-nav {
    display: none;
}
```

You forgot the # sign, which stand for html attribute `id`

```
id = #
class = .
```

Comment: That's very kind of you, thank you. Would I then place that code into the themes main styles.css file through editor?

Comment: yes. that's the place for it. better to put it in the child theme, but I don't want to complicate you :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `header.php` and find the `wp_nav_menu();` function.

Example:

```
    <div class="main-navigation">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'nav-name')); ?>
    </div>
```

You could wrap it in a check for the current page. `$post` is available as a global variable.

```
<?php if($post->post_name !== 'splash-page'): ?>
    <div class="main-navigation">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'nav-name')); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.

I pasted below code to custom css in divi theme

```
.page-id-28577 #top-menu-nav {
    display: none;
}
```

`.page-id-28577` = body class of the page that I don't want to show menu on

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

`.container.clearfix.et_menu_container {
    display: none;
}`